# Capitalize first letter after special characters

Tags: regex, r, uppercase, capitalization

I want to remove extra spaces, add spaces if required and capitalize first letter of each word after special character using R

```
string <- "apple,banana, cat, doll and donkey;     fish,goat"
```

I want output as

```
Apple, Banana, Cat, Doll and donkey; Fish, Goat
```

I tried

```
gsub("(^.|,.|;.)", "\\U\\1", string, perl=T, useBytes = F)
```

It didn't work. Please help

Comment: you need to allow for whitespace `gsub("(^.|[,;]\\s*.)", "\\U\\1", string, perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
string <- "apple,banana, cat, doll and donkey;     fish,goat"
trimws(gsub("(^|\\p{P})\\s*(.)", "\\1 \\U\\2", string, perl=T))
## => [1] "Apple, Banana, Cat, Doll and donkey; Fish, Goat"
```

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/izE9om)

The PCRE regex matches:

- `(^|\\p{P})` - (Group 1) start of string or any punctuation
- `\\s*` - 0 or more whitespace symbols
- `(.)` - (Group 2) any character but a newline

The replacement:

- `\\1` - backreferences Group 1
- - inserts a space between the punctuation and the next character or at the start of string
- `\\U\\2` - turns the Group 2 character uppercase

And `trimws` removes the initial space we added with the regex.